# Java - local class and generics, why compiler warning?

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

Named [local classes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#247766) are very rarely used, usually local classes are anonymous. Does anybody know why the code below generates a compiler warning?

```
public class Stuff<E> {
  Iterator<E> foo() {
    class InIterator implements Iterator<E> {
      @Override public boolean hasNext() { return false; }
      @Override public E next() { return null; }
      @Override public void remove() { }
    }
    return new InIterator();
  }
}
```

The warning is in `new InIterator()` and it says

```
[unchecked] unchecked conversion
found   : InIterator
required: java.util.Iterator<E>
```

If the class, unchanged, is made anonymous, or if it is made a member, the warning goes away. However, as a named local class, it requires a declaration `class InIterator<E> implements ...` for the warning to go away.

What's going on?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, my compiler doesn't complain about this warning ... What JVM are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now convinced that it's a javac bug. The solutions above that add a generic parameter to InIterator that either hides or replaces E aren't helpful, because they preclude the iterator from doing something useful, like returning an element of type E - Stuff's E.

However this compiles with no warnings (thanks Jorn for the hint):

```
public class Stuff<E> {
  E bar;
  Iterator<E> foo() {
    class InIterator<Z> implements Iterator<E> {
      @Override public boolean hasNext() { return false; }
      @Override public E next() { return bar;  }
      @Override public void remove() { }
    }
    return new InIterator<Void>();
  }
}
```

Definitely a bug.

Comment: Can you file a bug and post the link? You've gotten me all curious.

Comment: well, according to tweakt below there's no warning in update 13. I will check, but assuming he's right, it means it WAS a bug :-)

Comment: Ah, ok. Have you checked to see if it's in the bug list somewhere?

Comment: Didn't find it in http://bugs.sun.com nor in http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u13.html

Comment: Dunno about tweakt, for me 1.6.0_13 shows the same warning. Submitting a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what's happening is you are ignoring the generic type argument by naming `InIterator` without a reference to the generic in the signature (even though it is present in the interface).

This falls into the category of silly compiler warnings: you've written the class so that 100% `InIterator` instances will implement `Iterator<E>`, but the compiler doesn't recognize it.  (I suppose this depends on the compiler.  I don't see the warning in my Eclipse compiler, but I know that the Eclipse compiler handles generics slightly differently than the JDK compiler.)

I argue that this is less clear, and less close to what you mean, but perhaps more compiler friendly, and ultimately equivalent:

```
public class Stuff<E> {
  Iterator<E> foo() {
    class InIterator<F> implements Iterator<F> {
      @Override public boolean hasNext() { return false; }
      @Override public E next() { return null; }
      @Override public void remove() { }
    }
    return new InIterator<E>();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. IntelliJ IDEA also didn't show any warnings, just Sun javac. I know how to fix this, I am simply wondering if there is some strange but legitimate reason for this compiler behavior, or it's a bug.

Comment: Ahh, compiler differences between IDE and javac... how annoying :(

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me whether it's a bug that InIterator is not a Iterator<E> or that InIterator implements Iterator<E>.

Comment: It is legitimate if you have low expectations of the compiler, which is what I've come to have regarding generics.  If you expect the compiler to only do a quick logical pass-through when it asks "Is this guaranteed to be the right generic type?" then this is what you expect.  If you expect it to look back a little farther, then no, not legitimate.

Comment: Hi Jorn - I seriously suspect a compiler bug. JLS doesn't seem to differentiate named and anonymous local classes with regards to generics, so the code should compile. And why adding an unused parameter makes the warning go away?! like:
public class Stuff<E> {
  E bar;
  Iterator<E> foo() {
    class InIterator<Z> implements Iterator<E> {
      ...
      @Override public E next() { return bar;  }
      ...
    }
    return new InIterator<E>();
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, no warnings here.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Stuff<E> {
    Iterator<E> foo() {
        class InIterator implements Iterator<E> {
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return false;
            }

            public E next() {
                return null;
            }

            public void remove() {
            }
        }
        return new InIterator();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Iterator<String> i = new Stuff<String>().foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Tested inside of Eclipse (3.4), as well as with Sun JDK 1.5.0.18 and 1.6.0.13

Comment: there is a warning for Sun 1.6.0_11 and 1.6.0_12, I will check 13, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I also agree that this should be a bug. If you "lift" the local class out of the method into a member class, it works fine too. And there isn't much difference between the two except different scoping and access to local variables.

```
public class Stuff<E> {
  class InIterator implements Iterator<E> {
    @Override public boolean hasNext() { return false; }
    @Override public E next() { return null; }
    @Override public void remove() { }
  }
  Iterator<E> foo() {
    return new InIterator();
  }
}
```