# How to use the type parameter of a generic parent inside of local classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, inner-classes

Why can't I reference the type parameter of a generic parent class inside of contained local classes?

```
public class IsGeneric<T> {
    public void doSomething(T arg) {
        class A {
            T x;
        }

        A foo = new A();
        foo.x = arg;
        T bar = foo.x;  // error: found java.lang.Object, required T
    }
}
```

According to Eclipse the above code is perfectly fine, yet javac 1.6.0_11 seems to think that `foo.x` is of type java.lang.Object. A workaround to the problem is obviously to make `A` generic itself such as in the following code:

```
public class IsGeneric<T> {
    public void doSomething(T arg) {
        class A<S> {
            S x;
        }

        A<T> foo = new A<T>();
        foo.x = arg;
        T bar = foo.x;
    }
}
```

However, I would like to understand what's wrong with the first variant. Any ideas?

Comment: I know that it's the same in C#, but in C# you can just use `class A<T>` too, saving on a second generic parameter.

Comment: It's definitely not the same as in C#, given that C# doesn't even have local classes.

Comment: … and classes within classes differ fundamentally from the ones in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug in Sun's `javac`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772914/java-local-class-and-generics-why-compiler-warning) which includes possible solutions in the answers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It turned out to be a known bug of javac: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6657499